# Google Sheets one criteria with different and multiple results

Tags: google-sheets

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[REPAIR & MAINTENANCE REQUESTED BUDGET],SMALL(IF(Table1[MAKE/MODEL & YEAR]=$J$10,ROW(Table1[REPAIR & MAINTENANCE REQUESTED BUDGET])-ROW('R-M Tracker'!E$2)+1),ROWS('R-M Tracker'!E$2:E5))),"")}
```

The above code is what I use in MS Excel, here is a sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZmTQPOfWZUAR5Dwc-Vcydw7sAYbsiA26hN0i7_0ejs/edit?usp=sharing). What it does is it searches another sheet for all the records with the given criteria (value of J10). It then shows all the results in the summary report.

I've tried to replicate this on Google Sheets and use this code,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G5,'Comprehensive Insurance Renewal Record'!B2:C,2,false)))
```

Although it gives me a result, it only retrieves one and not every record that matches. I know I should add more to my code but I just don't have any idea what to add to achieve the result I want which is, it should display all matching records on their individual cells for the given criteria. Here is the sample of the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TDPWPLQPyvH6OiL8wIOSP5XvoxjfZDvBJMTYiF4WrIs/edit?usp=sharing) I'm currently working on. The given code above is written on "Vehicle Report" Sheet cell B14:B50.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: What you probably want to do is use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function; e.g. , `=QUERY('Comprehensive...'!B2:C, "select * where Col1 = '"&G5&"'")`

Comment: @Altigraph, Hi. I've tried this code.    =QUERY('Comprehensive Insurance Renewal Record'!B2:C28, "select C where (B = "&'Vehicle Report'!G5&")"). There's an error saying "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: GNIP". I think I'm doing the "Select" part wrong. Can you help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. For those who are interested, here is the correct code I used.

```
=QUERY('Comprehensive Insurance Renewal Record'!B2:C28, "select C where B contains '"&$G5&"'")
```